# Как выровнять все элементы контейнера с помощью flexbox?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, flexbox

У меня есть контейнер, в котором есть 5 тегов nav (элементов)

```
<div id="container">
    <nav id="elem">Example 1</nav>
    <nav id="elem">Example 2</nav>
    <nav id="elem">Example 3</nav>
    <nav id="elem">Example 4</nav>
    <nav id="elem">Example 5</nav>
</div>
```

И мне нужно чтобы они были в строку, и я мог ими управлять с помощью flexbox'а.

Comment: _"... и я мог ими управлять с помощью flexbox'а"_ Как Вы собираетесь управлять элементами в дальнейшем?

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/html/attr/id у вас id не уникальный

Answer (score 1):

[Управляйте](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%B2_Flex_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5):

```css
.flex__container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex__container">
    <nav class="flex__item">Example 1</nav>
    <nav class="flex__item">Example 2</nav>
    <nav class="flex__item">Example 3</nav>
    <nav class="flex__item">Example 4</nav>
    <nav class="flex__item">Example 5</nav>
</div>
```